# Is there a way to set an html5 output to a default value?

Tags: html, properties, range, onload, output

This code does not seems to work:

```
 <form onload= "x.value=parseInt(a.value)" oninput= "x.value = parseInt(a.value)" id="theinterval" >
    <input class='slidor' type="range" name="a" value="25">
    <h2><output name="x" for="a" ></output></h2>
    </form>
```

the additional property the I inserted is: onload= "x.value=parseInt(a.value)" but it does not helps at all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a side note: oninput support is incomplete (IE9) or inesistent (<=IE8) so a polyfill may be required. HTML5 has also introduced the valueAsNumber property of JavaScript input objects (specifically those of type number, date, and range). This returns the value as a number rather than as a string, this may be useful in your subsequent evaluations.

Answer (score 4):

Its amazing easy:

```
<output name="x" for="a">25</output>
```

And naturaly it is not supported in IE, so you are back to square one. Works in current Chrome, Opera, Firefox and Safari for Windows. I guess it works on Safari for Mac too, which is a few steps ahead of the windows version anyway, but I am not going to test it right now.

Works not in IE 8, "Yay!".

Answer (score 1):

Form tag does not have any onload attribute. So you need to use it but different eay. You can take help of other html tags which supports onload attributes (for example: body, div, etc) .

One of the possible solution can be using the "onload" attribute of body tag.
It would look like this:

```
<body onload="o.value = parseInt(a.value)">

<form onsubmit="return true" oninput="o.value = parseInt(a.value)">
  <input id="a" type="range" step="any" value="25">

  <output id="o" name="o"></output>
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: This did not worked, I tried the variations of div, span, b, etc.

Comment: you want this "25" to flush in the screen from the beginning? Is not that what you want?

Comment: Yes! I have seen that! But on my browser my solution works! :S Firefox does not support `<input type='range'>` according to this bug [report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344618) but it should works fine on chrome! 

Can you please recheck it by going to this [jsfiddle repo](http://jsfiddle.net/yfwBR/), or which version and browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
<form oninput= "x.value = a.valueAsNumber" id="theinterval" >
<input class='slidor' type="range" name="a" value="25">
<h2>
<output Class='outputo' name="x" for="a"></output>
<p> mins </p>
</h2>
</form>


<script>
;(function() {
$(".outputo").attr('value', $(".slidor").attr('value') )
})()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br"> 
<head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <title>output</title>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var items = document.querySelectorAll("OUTPUT");
      for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].defaultValue = 0;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value)">
    <input type="number" id="a" value="0">+
    <input type="number" id="b" value="0">=
    <output id="out" name="x" for="a b"></output>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```